# How to calibrate the camera for AprilTag pose estimation ? (Python)

Tags: python, camera-calibration, pose-estimation, apriltags

maybe it alreday asked but I don't find information.
I would like to use April tag marker to track an object rather than Aruco marker to try another solution. So I need to do a pose estimation and and I suppose that it is necessary to give camera calibration data (as for Aruco pose methods) but I do not understand how it is done. Where do we specify this calibration data ? in which method ?

I barely understand that we pass this data through "camera_params" parameter in Detector.detect() but in all example I found I was magic number and I don't understand how to get this data.

ps : I use pupil_apriltags, python 3.10.11, opencv 4.7.0 and I'm on Windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see that with opencv (as "import cv2")  can detect AprilTag markers, so I can use my scirpts that already work with aruco marker. In this case, is it better to use pupil-apriltag module or directly opencv ?

Seems like the two librairies are not implemented in the same way, so I suppose there are diffrences.